# Simple Sample Loop in R

Tags: r

I have a data set of 52 numbers ( some are the same number) and from this data set I need to take 2000 samples of size five.  How do I do this in R console using sample and loop functions?

Comment: Take a look at `sample` and `replicate`.

Comment: Do the samples of 5 need to be unique or is it all sampled with replacement?

Answer (score 3):

`sample` and `replicate` could be a useful combination here.

```
> # generating a data set consisting of 52 numbers
> set.seed(1)
> numbers <- sample(1:30, 52, TRUE) # a vector of 52 numbers, your sample
> 
> # 20 samples of size five (I chose 10 intead of 2000 for this example)
> set.seed(2)
> results <- replicate(10, sample(numbers, 5))
> results
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    2   21   27   16   25   12    8   15   26    20
[2,]   21   29   21   21   24   20   19   17   15    21
[3,]   27   20   22    6   20   30   25   24   27    30
[4,]   19   20   19    7   20   15   24   26   20     9
[5,]   24    1   24   28   22   29    9   20   24    22
```

Each sample is stored by column in the matrix called `results`. The following codes will give you the answer you're looking for. Note there are two alternatives, setting `replace=TRUE` or `replace=FALSE` is to allow sampling with replacement or without replacement.

```
results1 <- replicate(2000, sample(numbers, 5, replace=TRUE)) # sampling with replacement
results2 <- replicate(2000, sample(numbers, 5, replace=FALSE))  # sampling without replacement
```

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that if you're sampling with replacement (you didn't specify) 2000 samples of size 5 is no different than 10,000 samples divided into groups of 5.

```
Y <- sample(x, 10000, replace = TRUE)
```

You can divide that up a number of ways, You could make a `data.frame` for long format or a `matrix` for wide.

```
# long format
dat <- data.frame(id = rep(1:5, 2000), Y)

# wide format
dat <- matrix(Y, nrow = 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't need loops here, avoid loops in R if you can.
You can use the `replicate` function: this return a matrix so that each 'replicate' will be a column (by default):

```
# x = your data here

n.samples = 2000
sample.size = 5
do.replace = FALSE
sample.matrix = replicate(n.samples, sample(x, sample.size, replace = do.replace))

print(sample.matrix)
```